# Strange behaviour in arrays. Random elements

Tags: ruby, arrays

I was doing some operations with arrays, like this (very simple)

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [1]
b.push((a-b).sample)
=> [1, 2]
```

Ok, let's see some times its value

```
b
=> [1, 2]
b
=> [1, 3]
b
=> [1, 2]
b
=> [1, 4]
```

I don't understand why b changes. I supposed that i took a random element from de difference between a and b, and append it to b, so... where am i wrong?

EDIT:

Today is a new day, and magically, the same code runs ok.... it's a mistery
Thank's all!

Comment: I cannot reproduce that: https://gist.github.com/8ca38af6a5574fe17417

Comment: That seems pretty strange that each time you inspect b it has different values.  This is just in a naked irb session?  There's no other thread with a reference to b hanging around?

Comment: @dominikh you are getting what i supposed to get with that code

Comment: @dbenhur, i have closed all my irb sessions, opened a new console, and get that result again... it's so strange

Comment: you say "new console". Is that a rails console, or just irb?  Do you load anything in .irbrc?

Comment: just irb console, without load anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you expect to get?

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = []
0.upto(3) do
    b.push((a-b).sample)
    puts b
end

  #=>  [2]
  #=>  [2, 4]
  #=>  [2, 4, 1]
  #=>  [2, 4, 1, 3]
```

Comment: Yes. I just want to get a random element and add it to an existing array, but i don't want that those random elements that i get before change.
Do you know why am i getting this strange behaviour? Why those elements that I push into b change many times?

Comment: @Imanol There is no strange behavior on this. Try to clear your question, and explain better what's happening

Comment: @ismaelga his question shows he pushes to b once, then inspects b several times. Each inspection shows b with different contents, yet no mutating method has been called on b after the initial push. That's what's strange.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation @dbenhur, I'm trying to improve my english

Comment: Oh.. I can't help on this then... Will delete my answer